# Need help making code elegant with regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'll start right away by saying that I am not a programmer but I do like to poke around things and learn. Here's what I have:

1) URL in the following format: `http://site.com/#!/show/me/stuff/1-12/`

2) jQuery pagination script that outputs the # of available pages. Each number is a link with `href="#pageNumber"`

3) jQuery script that binds to all pagination links. The function code is below.

Basically, my goal is to replace 1-12 in my URL with the proper values if, say, I select page #2.

Here's what I cooked up that works but is extremely ugly:

```
var pageId = this.href.split("#")[1]; 
// this gets the number from the pagination link (i.e.,
// http://site.com/#2 becomes 2)

var url = location.hash.split("/");
var url = url[url.length-2];
// this is my way of extracting "1-12" from the URL :)

var showFrom = parseFloat(url.split("-")[0]); // 1
var showTo = parseFloat(url.split("-")[1]); // 12
var itemsPerPage= (showTo-showFrom)+1; // 12
var newShowTo = (itemsPerPage*pageId); // 24
var newShowFrom = (itemsPerPage*pageId)-itemsPerPage+1; // 13
var newUrl = newShowFrom+"-"+newShowTo; // 13-24

location.hash = location.hash.replace(url, newUrl);
// http://site.com/#!/show/me/stuff/1-12/ now becomes
// http://site.com/#!/show/me/stuff/13-24/
```

How can I make this more elegant and in fewer steps?

Comment: Aside - since you're using integers, use parseInt(), not parseFloat().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is not that ugly - the variable names are self explanatory and I can assure you we have all seen things that are *much worse*.

Anyway, here is a way to do the same thing as you did but using regexes:

```
var pageId = this.href.split("#")[1];   
var pattern = /\/(\d+)-(\d+)\/?$/;
location.hash = location.hash.replace(pattern, function(_, showFrom_str, showTo_str){
    var showFrom = parseInt(showFrom_str, 10);
    var showTo   = parseInt(showTo_str, 10);
    var itemsPerPage = showTo - showFrom + 1;
    return '/' + ((itemsPerPage * pageId) - itemsPerPage + 1) + '-' + (itemsPerPage * pageId) + '/';
});
```

**How it works:**

*The pattern*: slash `\/`, followed by one or more `+` digits `\d`, followed by a hyphen `-`, followed by another sequence of digits `(\d+)`, followed by an optional `?` slash `\/`, followed by the end of the string `$`.

*The substitution*: We can pass a substitution function to the replace method so that we have the replacement text depend of the replaced text. The first argument to the function is the whole match (`"/1-12/"`) and we ignore it (`_` is a convention for "ignore this").

The next arguments correspond to the captured patterns in the regex - those things wrapped by parenthesis. In your case, the arguments are the string representations of the numbers for the start and the end of the range.

I then just use the same logic as you did, except that

- I used parseInt instead of parseFloat. (Don't forget about the second parameter for the base though or "08" can bite you)
- I used less intermediate variables.

---

In the end all the regex was get rid of the string splitting and streamline the code a bit. However, in a real situation I would probably try to think about a more robust solution that did not depend on fragile string operations on the URL.

Comment: well done and explained! thank you very much; I'll get to learn from your optimized solution.

as for the more robust way of doing things, I am not sure how I would go about doing that without overcomplicating things; every parameter in the hash URL is validated by the server when a request is made, so if something's not right with it, I redirect visitors back to the starting page or display an error message.

Comment: I've just noticed that the code works going forward, but not backwards (pageId, or the page # that is being clicked on, was omitted from your elegant solution).